# Allow only capital and small letters

Tags: php, html

I would like to accept only small and capital letters from the user.

I tried the below code, it echoes the invalid character message but doesn't work. I mean it doesn't check. It just displays the message. Any help?

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
</form>
```

**Update:** this is what I have to check and insert the name to database. if numbers found in the name reject the name by displaying the error message else if the name contains only letters insert it into database. That's all I want to acheive.

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
$fname = $_POST["fname"];

if(!preg_match ('/^([a-zA-Z]+)$/', $fname)){
echo "Invalid characters";
}

if (empty($fname)) {
echo  '<span> First name is required</span>';
}

else{
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test (firstname) VALUES (?)");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $fname);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();


}
}
?>
```

Comment: its written just above. its a post variable

Comment: what you mean by that? it gets the user input from the form.

Comment: @alte  if you want to allow only letters then use javascript

Comment: @diEcho what if the user disable javascript?

Comment: If it echoes "Invalid characters" that means it's working.  I'm confused?

Comment: @diEcho JavaScript can be manipulated. It would be a nice start but it shouldn't be the only means of validation as it cannot be trusted.

Comment: Yes, But apply `JS` code first then go for server side checking. why you every time want to force server to check all things. Suppose user doesn't disabled JS then!!

Comment: also check that POST is set

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to check you could use [ctype_alpha()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) but you said you want to *ACCEPT* only letters so if you choose to accept the input you could:

```
$fname=preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i','',$fname);
```

better after the check

Comment: thanks. it's better removing unwanted characters than allowing user to send whatever they want.

Comment: This, I like this approach! Strip all the bad stuff out, and  validate with client-side js if it is a web app type of thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!isset($_POST['fname']) || !ctype_alpha($_POST['fname'])){
  // can i haz alpha letters only?
}
```

([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php))

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code, and the one you are stuck with is probably that you have the form and its processing in the same PHP file. That’s possible, but it requires a different approach. For a starter, it’s probably better to separate them.

What happens with the code posted is that the PHP processor tries to process the form data when no form has been submitted, without even checking for the presence of the data. Now `$fname` is undefined, so the test always fails.

The test is wrong, too. Now it only checks whether `$fname` contains at least one letter. For example, `if(!preg_match ('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $fname))` would test that `$fname` consists of one or more Ascii letters and nothing else.

Comment: I have the form and the php in the same page and it is not an issue because I made the php run only when submit is pressed. Actually I didn't include that part when posting the code here...for the test part, It is what I'm trying to do.  my aim is not to just check if there is a number but reject the input if there is a number in it.

Answer (score 0):

use this , this is giving me correct answer

```
if(!preg_match ('/^([a-zA-Z]+)$/', $fname)){
    echo "Invalid characters";
}
else{
    echo "correct";
}
```

Comment: What I want is to show the single error, I mean like..if the user enter number I would let him know the error and go to my else statement instead of returning true if the input matches only letters..

Comment: This pattern will match any input string. The variant with `+` will still match strings containing any number of non-letter characters, as long as there's at least one letter.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of checking for characters that don't match the `[a-zA-Z]` pattern is a good one.

However, the "not" part of your `if` condition is in the wrong place if you want this to work. What you've got now just makes sure that *any single* character in `fname` is an upper- or lower-case Latin letter.

You want to push the "not" part of the logic into the pattern:

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $fname)) {
```

This checks if any character in `fname` is not a Latin letter, which is what you're trying to do.

**Edit:** Your new update has a different test that also works (it appears to be from sourcecode's updated answer, but you've got several tests from the different answers here that will work equally well). But, your updated post makes it clear that your problem isn't really with the pattern for testing the name.

Your code looks like this:

```
if (/* invalid fname */) {
    echo "Invalid characters";
}

if (/* empty fname */) {
    echo  '<span> First name is required</span>';
}

else {
    /* insert into database */
}
```

That `else` clause only depends on the the `if` that comes immediately before it: the check whether `fname` is empty. In other words, regardless of the result of your check against the characters of `fname`, you insert it into the database whenever it's not empty.

One easy way to fix this is to just change your second `if` to an `elseif`. This will chain all three conditionals together, so the final `else` block will only occur if *both* of the earlier conditionals that print error messages weren't triggered.

```
if (/* empty fname */) {
    echo  'First name is required.';
}

elseif (/* invalid fname */) {
    echo 'Invalid characters';
}

else {
    /* insert into database */
}
```

Comment: Is the code you posted exactly as it is in your script? Your posted code has a syntax error: the closing brace of the `else` clause is hidden as part of the "do something" comment.